# How can one display tables side by side in Github Markdown?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

For instance, this doesn't work, tables are joined:

```
| Tables   |      Are      |  Cool |             | Tables   |      Are      |  Cool |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|             |----------|:-------------:|------:|
| col 1 is |  left-aligned | $1600 |             | col 1 is |  left-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is |    centered   |   $12 |             | col 2 is |    centered   |   $12 |
| col 3 is | right-aligned |    $1 |
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this isn't possible, even with embedded HTML.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Space between text marks the beginning and end of particular types of content. Try this:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Table 1 Heading 1 </th><th>Table 1 Heading 2</th></tr>
<tr><td>

|Table 1| Middle | Table 2|
|--|--|--|
|a| not b|and c |

</td><td>

|b|1|2|3| 
|--|--|--|--|
|a|s|d|f|

</td></tr> </table>
```

It will look like this:

[image: two merkdown tables in one html table]

Comment: OK, I've awarded it, but it doesn't work for me :(, I'm using marked to convert to HTML. I guess it can't be done...

Comment: @igorludi That's surprising given the "why" of it working in github. If you open a question with the detail of how you are using marked and post the link here, I'd happily have a look

Comment: @igorludi I think thats a bug with marked: if i make the third line `<tr><td><table></table>` then it works in marked too. Whatever way you look at that, its a bug :)

Comment: is it possible to have a merged common heading ?

Comment: yes, @Cfun that would just be a case of having a colspan in the heading: `<tr><th colspan=2>Table 1 Heading 1 </th></tr>`

Comment: Didn't tested yet but probably it will work  thanks :) you can add as a note maybe to your answer if you want.

Answer (score 9):

For GitHub, you can use the below format for displaying two tables side by side. This is the way I usually do it:

```
|Table 1|Table 2|
|--|--|
|<table> <tr><th>Table 1 Heading 1</th><th>Table 1 Heading 2</th></tr><tr><td>Row 1 Column 1</td><td>Row 1 Column 2</td></tr> </table>| <table> <tr><th>Table 2 Heading 1</th><th>Table 2 Heading 2</th></tr><tr><td>Row 1 Column 1</td><td>Row 1 Column 2</td></tr> </table>|
```

You can see the output [here](https://gist.github.com/jagrutkosti/d85557777008d78f44d156039342bcfc).

Note: Please do not use new line or it will not work.

Comment: Sorry, but this is one MD table, with HTML in two cells, I'm looking for pure markdown, or at least for the outer table to be HTML (since it will always be small - 1x2 table).

Comment: @igorludi You can reverse them and make outer table HTML and inner one MD. An example is given in the answer by spacepickle. Pure markdown in not possible, as per my knowledge.